# Can't read GCS credentials from file

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have mounted my Google Cloud Platform credentials file as a volume in my docker container and I use docker-compose to create the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable from this file. When I go into the docker container, the file  is there and it's readable and the contents are correct, however when I inspect the content of the environment variable this is what gets returned:

```
docker exec -it -u celery container_name sh
/opt/ori $ $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
/opt/ori/application_default_credentials.json: line 2: type:: not found
/opt/ori/application_default_credentials.json: line 3: project_id:: not found
/opt/ori/application_default_credentials.json: line 4: private_key_id:: not found
/opt/ori/application_default_credentials.json: line 5: private_key:: not found
/opt/ori/application_default_credentials.json: line 6: client_email:: not found
/opt/ori/application_default_credentials.json: line 7: client_id:: not found
/opt/ori/application_default_credentials.json: line 8: auth_uri:: not found
/opt/ori/application_default_credentials.json: line 9: token_uri:: not found
/opt/ori/application_default_credentials.json: line 10: auth_provider_x509_cert_url:: not found
/opt/ori/application_default_credentials.json: line 11: client_x509_cert_url:: not found
```

Obviously it's partially reading the JSON file because it extracts the keys, but why can't it find the values?

Answer (score 0):

This statement `/opt/ori $ $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is treating the credentials file as an executable and trying to execute it as a script.

This line `/opt/ori/application_default_credentials.json: line 2: type:: not found` shows you that the operating system could not find the program `type::` to execute.